# how to count the pixels in roi opencv

Tags: opencv, pixel, image-size, roi

I have an cropped image of a coin. and I've already applied mask so i can focus on the coin itself. Next is I want to count the number of pixels of this coin. I've already read similar posts but i they just don't seem to work for me.

here is the original image:
http://s30.postimg.org/eeh3lp99d/IMG_20150414_121300.jpg

and the cropped coin:
http://s3.postimg.org/4k2pdst73/cropped.png

HEre is my code so far:

```
//get the number of pixels of the coin 
//STEP 1: CROP THE COIN 
//get the Rect containing he circl 
Rect rectCircle(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2); //obtain the image ROI: 
Mat roi(src_gray, rectCircle); 
//make a black mask, same size: 
Mat mask(roi.size(), roi.type(), Scalar::all(0)); 
//with a white,filled circle in it: 
circle(mask, Point(radius, radius), radius, Scalar::all(255), -1); 
//combine roi and mask: 
cv::Mat coin_cropped = roi & mask;
```

How do i count the number of pixels of the cropped coin?

Comment: remember to post the code you have so far

Comment: here's what i have so far..     `//get the number of pixels of the coin
   //STEP 1: CROP THE COIN
   //get the Rect containing he circl
   Rect rectCircle(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
   //obtain the image ROI:
   Mat roi(src_gray, rectCircle);
   //make a black mask, same size:
   Mat mask(roi.size(), roi.type(), Scalar::all(0));
   //with a white,filled circle in it:
   circle(mask, Point(radius, radius), radius, Scalar::all(255), -1);
   //combine roi and mask:
   cv::Mat coin_cropped = roi & mask;
   `

Comment: on your mask use cv::countNonZero function

Comment: @Micka, where do i insert it cv::countNonZero? thank you so much. I'm such a noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [countnonzero](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero)

> countNonZero
>
> Counts non-zero array elements.
>
> C++: int countNonZero(InputArray src)

Use this on the ROI matrix and it will return an int of the number of pixels, in your code it will look like this:

```
numberOfPixelsInMask = cv::countNonZero(mask);
```